# Preventing Previously Merged Development Branch Commits from Appearing in Feature Branch PR Diffs on GitHub

Tags: git, github

What I Want to Resolve
I am currently struggling with a branching strategy.

There are development and feature branches, and commits are made to each branch. I am considering periodically incorporating the development branch into the feature branch. I create a pull request (PR) by branching off from the feature branch, merging the development branch into it, and then merging that branch into the feature branch.

However, this results in the content of the development branch that was previously incorporated into the feature branch being displayed in the PR difference. I believe this is likely due to the fact that the difference in GitHub's PR is based on the triple dot.

If I want to periodically incorporate the development branch without displaying previously incorporated changes as part of the PR difference, what kind of operation should I adopt?

Comment: Are you squash-merging?

Comment: I am not 100% sure I understand what development/feature branch are in your question, but I think you want the `git fetch`+`git rebase` workflow.

Comment: @eftshift0
Yes, that's correct.
squash-merging

Comment: If you are merging a long-running branch into a branch, then _do not squash merge_..... cause when you squash-merge, git **does not** create any relation to the commits of the branch you are merging.

Comment: Thank you.
Is it possible to create a PR on GitHub for the purpose of reviewing changes (differences incorporated from the development branch) made locally?

I understand it to be impossible, but...

@LokiRagnarok

Comment: @原裕貴 You want to develop locally and compare with upstream (that is, what you forked from?) You can make a fork of the original project, push your branch there, and then start a PR without clicking submit (on the screen where you will be asked for summary etc). Alternatively, you can configure multiple remotes and run a `git diff` specifically against the upstream remote (instead of the default that you would push to).

Comment: "create a PR locally to review changes?" – you can just use `git diff development feature` …